# Get difference between two times in hh:mm:ss format

Tags: sql, mysql

So I want to find the time difference between these 2 columns and add that result as a new column ride_length

| started_at | ended_at | ride_length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2021-02-12 16:14:56' | '2021-02-12 16:21:43' | '00:06:47' |
| '2021-02-14 17:52:38' | '2021-02-14 18:12:09' | '00:19:31' |

So when I do this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, started_at, ended_at)) AS time_diff
from `cyclist`.`2021`;
```

It gives me the result I want, but adding a create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `schema`.`table2`
     SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, started_at, ended_at)) AS time_diff
     from `cyclist`.`2021`;
```

it returns:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect time value: '3235296'
```

I've also tried creating a column with the difference between `started_at` and `ended_at being` in seconds and then doing `sec_to_time(seconds)` but that returns the same error code.

Comment: Specify the table structure explicitly: ```CREATE TABLE schema.table2 (time_diff TIME) SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, started_at, ended_at)) from cyclist.2021;```

Comment: Does the `timediff()` function do what you need? minimum example: `select timediff(cast('2021-02-12 16:21:43' as datetime), cast('2021-02-12 16:14:56' as datetime));`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle DATE data type stores 7 informations: century, year, month, day, hour, minute and second. If we substract date from another date we will get the result in days. So, to get what you want the result  should be transformed into hours, minutes and seconds with some concatinations..

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (STARTED_AT, ENDED_AT) AS
        ( Select To_Date('2021-02-12 16:14:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2021-02-12 16:21:43', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual Union All
          Select To_Date('2021-02-14 17:52:38', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2021-02-14 18:12:09', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') From Dual
        )
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select  STARTED_AT, ENDED_AT, 
        LPAD( FLOOR((ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT) * 24), 2, '0') || ':' ||      -- hours
        LPAD( FLOOR(((ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT) * 24 * 60) - (FLOOR((ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT) * 24) * 60)), 2, '0') || ':' ||   -- minutes
        LPAD(Round(((ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT) * 24 * 60 * 60) -                                                              -- seconds
        (FLOOR((ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT) * 24) * 60 * 60 ) - 
        ((FLOOR(((ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT) * 24 * 60) - (FLOOR((ENDED_AT - STARTED_AT) * 24) * 60))) * 60 ), 0), 2, '0') "RIDE_LENGTH"
From    tbl

/*    R e s u l t :
STARTED_AT          ENDED_AT            RIDE_LENGTH
------------------- ------------------- -----------
2021-02-12 16:14:56 2021-02-12 16:21:43 00:06:47
2021-02-14 17:52:38 2021-02-14 18:12:09 00:19:31    */
```